# Using a generation to express $a_n$

Tags: combinatorics

Consider the sequence $a_1, a_2, a_3, . . .$ where $a_n $denotes the number of ways to write n as an ordered sum of 1s and 2s. i.e. $a_n$ is the number of compositions of n in which each summand is either 1 or 2. Show that $a_n$ is the coefficient of $ x^n$
in

$g(x) = \frac{1}{1-x-x^2}$ let $g(y) = \frac{1}{1-y}$ then $1+y+y^2+... = 1+(x+x^2)+(x+x^2)^2 + (x+x^2)^3 +... = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (x+x^2)^{n} $ which makes no sense cause $x^{2i}=x^k$ where i is less than k so ill get repeated terms and my coefficient wont be right. anyone got an ideas how to find the the right coefficent for $a_n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression given for $g(x)$ is in fact correct. 
The repeated terms are in fact necessary for the coefficients to come out right.

Here is the derivation:

Consider forming a composition which is counted in $a_n$.  The last number in that composition is either $1$ or $2$.  If it is $1$, then there are $a_{n-1}$ compositions of the preceding numbers, which have to ad to $n-1$.  If it is 
$2$, then there are $a_{n-2}$ compositions of the preceding numbers, which have to ad to $n-2$. So
$$
a_n = a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}
$$
This works for $n\geq 2$ and for $n=1$ if we consider $a_0=1$ (there is only one way to get a sum of zero: no $1$'s or $2$'s). But we want an equation that works for all integer $n$ so that we can freely shift indices (by shifting the exponents)  in the sums defining the generatiing function. 
When $n< 0$ we can arbitrarily say that $a_n=0$. So the general-$n$ equation is
$$
a_n = a_{n-1}+a_{n-2} +[n=0]
$$
where the notation $[n=0]$ is understood to mean "$1$ if $n=0$ and $0$ otherwise."

Now consider the generating function $g(x) = \sum g_nx^n$.
$$
g(x) =\sum_n g_nx^n= \sum_n g_{n-1}x^n + \sum_n g_{n-2}x^n + \sum_n [n=0]x^n
\\ = \sum_ng_nx^{n+1} + \sum_ng_nx^{n+2}+1 = x\,g(x) + x^2 g(x) + 1 \\
g(x) = x^2 g(x) + x\,g(x)  + 1  \implies g(x) (1-x-x^2) = 1 \\
g(x) = \frac1{1-x-x^2}
$$

By the way, this should be almost familiar, as the generating function for the FIbonacci numbers, shifted by $1$ position.

Comment: This explained what was going on for me the best thank you. ( we havent done much with generating function was like a 2 class thing that showed up at the end of a graphy theory and combinatorics /  some other random finite math introductory course (posets etc).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
Write $$g(x)=\sum _{i=0}^{\infty} b_ix^i=\frac{1}{1-x-x^2},$$
hence $$1=(1-x-x^2)\sum _{i=0}^{\infty}b_ix^i,$$
can you find a recursion for $b_i$? Is it satisfied by your $a_i?$ does $b_0=a_0$ and $b_1=a_i$?

Comment: Im sorry but i dont understand what your doing at all it looks like its a faster way of doing this but i have never seen this before.

Comment: 0k, sometimes sequences of numbers respect a recurrence relation. In this case it does. If you want to prove that they are in the generating function then you have to see that  they have the same relation and the same basis.

Comment: If you multiply the second expression i put you get $$1=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}b_ix^i-\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}b_{i-1}x^i-\sum_{i=2}^{\infty}b_{i-2}x^i,$$ so comparing coefficients in the equality you get $b_0 = 1$ and $b_i=b_{i-1}+b_{i-2}$ and this is satisfied by the $a_i$ because you can put at the end a $2$ in $a_{i-2}$ ways or a $1$ in $a_{i-1}$ ways.

Comment: wow i really like that way of approaching the problem thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your derivation is correct. I am not sure where your concern is, but it may help to do a concrete example.

Suppose you want $a_4$.

- $(x+x^2)^2$ contributes $x^4$ which represents $4=2+2$
- $(x+x^2)^3$ contributes $3x^4$ which represents $4=1+1+2=1+2+1=2+1+1$
- $(x+x^2)^4$ contributes $x^4$ which represents $4=1+1+1+1$

The point is that the coefficient of $x^k$ in $(x+x^2)^n$ will enumerate all ordered compositions of $k$ consisting of $n$ addends. Thus the coefficient of $x^k$ in $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (x+x^2)^n$ enumerates all ordered compositions of $k$ with any number of addends.